# Select Element in XML with Element with certain Attribute(Text)

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I'm currently trying to locate all users in an exported database which are not disabled with PowerShell.
I got a XML-file which is structured like this:

```
<database>
<table name="USERS">
        <entry>
            <cell name="ID">1</cell>
            <cell name="LOGINNAME">admin</cell>
            <cell name="ISDELETED">FALSE</cell>
            <cell name="STATIC">TRUE</cell>
            
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <cell name="ID">2</cell>
            <cell name="LOGINNAME">admin2</cell>
            <cell name="ISDELETED">TRUE</cell>
            <cell name="STATIC">TRUE</cell>
            
        </entry>
        
</table>
</database>
```

The problem is: The attributes inside  are all named "name" and I want to select only the  elements where ISDELETED=TRUE.

I tried it with XPath but I don't know how to get the text after I select the  with [@name='ID']

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content .\db.xml
$xml |Select-Xml "/database/table[@name='USERS']/entry/cell[@name='ID']" | foreach {$_}
```

Does anyone have an idea? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get the correct entries:

```
/database/table[@name='USERS']/entry[cell[@name='ISDELETED' and text()='FALSE']]
```

If you want a list of user ID's use this:

```
/database/table[@name='USERS']/entry[cell[@name='ISDELETED' and text()='FALSE']]/cell[@name='ID']/text()
```

If you want a list of user names use this:

```
/database/table[@name='USERS']/entry[cell[@name='ISDELETED' and text()='FALSE']]/cell[@name='LOGINNAME']/text()
```

Comment: Perfect! In combination with @iRon Answer with member-access enumeration it does exactly what I tried to achive! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You might just use PowerShell's `Xml` dot notation and the [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration) feature for this:

```
$Entry = $Xml.Database.Table.Entry.Where{
    $_.cell.name -eq 'ISDELETED' -and $_.cell.'#text' -eq 'TRUE'
}
$Entry.cell.Where{ $_.name -eq 'LOGINNAME' }.'#text'
```

```
admin2
```

To iterate through all the found entries and e.g. list the cells as a [PSCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobjec):

```
$Entry.ForEach{
    $Properties =[Ordered]@{}
    $_.Cell.ForEach{ $Properties[$_.Name] = $_.'#Text' }
    [PSCustomObject]$Properties
}
```

```
ID LOGINNAME ISDELETED
-- --------- ---------
2  admin2    TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but if there are any other <cell> with value "TRUE" it returns them too. I uploaded only a extract of the real database.

Comment: Isn't that were you asked for? Anyways, what else do you expect if there are multiple entries with `ISDELETED=TRUE`? Just return the first occurrence, narrow the filter? The point is that you not only need to specify the `name` attribute to filter the specific entry, but also require to specify the `name` for each cell that you want to iterate (unless you use [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration)). To make things more clear, I have updated the answer

Comment: I added another  <cell> with Text value "TRUE" to the. Question. In this case both entries will be selected. admin and admin2.
But with the addition you posted it works with member-access enumeration. Then it is the same "object" where I can work with Where-Object